# Data Validation Using Functions

Tags: python, function, validation

How do I create a function that validates the following?

```
def get_order():
    order=int(input("Select an item number: "))
    return order
```

I tried this:

```
def validate_order(order_choice):
    order_choice=get_order()
    return order_choice
    while order_choice < 1 or order_choice > 8:
        order_choice=int(input("Invalid value. Re-enter item number: "))
        return order_choice
```

I am confused on how to use parameters correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not put the validation logic in `get_order`

Comment: I don't understand why you put stuff after a `return` statement. These lines are **never** going to be called.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It's for a homework assignment, and the instructions state the validation must have its own function. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: You're using the params just fine - just remove the extra return, and place the final return outside the while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_order():
    order=int(input("Select an item number: "))
    return order
```

The validation:

```
def validate_order(order_choice):
    order_choice=get_order()
    while order_choice < 1 or order_choice > 8:
        order_choice=int(input("Invalid value. Re-enter item number: "))
    return order_choice
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you want to validate that the order number is indeed an integer.

To do this we will use the `isinstance()` function. Which accepts a variable and a type and returns `True` or `False` depending on whether or not it matches the second argument.

In your case it will look like this:

```
order = input("Select an item number: ")
while isinstance(order, int) or order not in xrange(1,9):
    order = get_order("Invalid value. Re-enter item number: ")
```